# putty - network is unreachable error

Tags: networking, ssh, putty, ipv6

Yesterday I bought a cloud server from vultr.com (ipv6 version). I'm trying to connect to my server via PuTTy; however, when I entered the ip address of my server and hit enter, it gives the error "network is unreachable". I think that this problem's related to the server being ipv6 because I have never experienced a problem with ipv4 servers I bought from the same site. How can I solve this?

Edit: I use Windows 10.

Comment: Hi there, can you add the putty version and operating system? also are you able to ping the IP?

Comment: Do you have IPv6 connectivity from your PC to your server, meaning in your local network, from your ISP, appropriate routers, etc?

Comment: Hi Jorge. I use Windows 10 and can't ping the IP either. When I tried to ping it from cmd, it gives "PING: transmit failed. General failure" error. As for the version of putty, I couldn't find which version it is.

Answer (score 3):

Likely one of three things.

1. You don't have ipv6 connectivity at your PC while you're running putty. If you need to have it, you can use something like tunnelbroker.net and create an ipv4 to ipv6 tunnel. This will give you ipv6 ip addresses. To test for ipv6 connectivity head over to http://ipv6-test.com/
2. You have an outdated version of putty. ipv6 is supported from version 0.58 onwards.
3. You need to enclose an ipv6 address in square brackets [ ] for putty to recognize the address as such.